# Basic files structure using require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs

If I had *page1.html* and *page2.html*, on *page1.html* I would require to use some scripting which requires *jquery*, and *page2.html* would require to use some scripting which requires *jquery* and *underscore*.

According to my little knowledge, I just use

page1.html

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="page1.js"></script>
```

page2.html

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="underscore.js"></script>
<script src="page2.js"></script>
```

How should I structure my app by taking avantages from underscore.js?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add require.js at the bottom of the html body tag, add

```
<script src="js/libs/require/require.js" data-main="js/main"></script>
```

Using require.js, in a file named 'main.js' you put this:

```
//Require.js 
require.config({

    baseUrl: 'js', 

    paths   : {
        jquery                  : '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min', 
        underscore              : 'libs/underscore/underscore-min'
    },  

    shim    : {
        underscore: {
          exports: '_'
        }
    }
});
```

Within your custom js file (the module that you want to create), add:

```
define([
  'jquery', 
  'underscore', 
  'page2'
], function($, _, Page2){

    //Specify module here 
    var someObj = {}; 
    return someObj
});
```

This should be either define or require, depending on the use of the module. 
As you can see, you can also add custom javascript files, if they contain any javascript functions that you need in your current module.

In case of a multiple paged application, I found this resource:
https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage

> This project shows how to set up a multi-page requirejs-based project
>   that has the following goals:
>
> Each page uses a mix of common and page-specific modules.
>   All pages share the same requirejs config. After an optimization build, the
>   common items should be in a shared common layer, and the page-specific
>   modules should be in a page-specific layer.
>   The HTML page should not have to be changed after doing the build.

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I'm still don't get all them, 1. **within the js file** means *page1.js* and *page2.js*? 2. How *page1.html* knows about *page1.js* because it's only link to main.js?

Comment: I added a resource that shows an example of how to use require.js for a multipaged web application.